# Adding Datatable to List<Datatable>, data being persisted through add(). Why?

Tags: c#

I have the need to add 1-* datatables to a `List<Datatable>`. On the first iteration through, I confirm that the appropriate data has been loaded into the datatable that then gets added to my List.

However upon the second iteration, I"m noticing that the first item that was added has been overwritten by the data of the second item and so and so on.

I tried this here, in hopes that creating a new Datatable and adding to the list would help, but I'm still running into the same issue.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = _dtDetails;                 // _dtdetails is my datatable
_dtDetailsList.Add(dt);          // _dtDetailsList is my List<Datatable>
```

This should be just a straight forward add. I'm doing similar things elsewhere in code and it's not having the same end result as this. There is nothing special about this list or the datatable. Normal stuff. Thoughts?

Comment: Show the whole loop around your add

Comment: `dt = _dtDetails` won't create a deep copy of `_dtDetails`; it only causes `dt` to point to the same object that `_dtDetails` points to.  If you're doing that in your loop, that may be the cause of your problem.  Can you post the loop code?

Comment: The add occurs outside of a loop. The loop above adds data to _dtDetails and then I catch it outside and am trying to add to this list. Is there a way of adding to a list by val as opposed to by ref? Would just creating a new instance of _dtDetails above the loop each time it goes to hit it solve my problem? I'm going to try that.

Comment: the instruction dt=new DataTable won't be taken into account, because you assign something else to dt in the next instruction.

Comment: Again, it would be helpful to see the actual loop, rather than just having a description of the loop.